# WPF: Mysql connection on remote server

Tags: mysql, wpf, database, centos, remote-server

I was trying to connect my WPF application to a remote server with mysql. I've connected the application to localhost using mysql before and everything worked well. The remote server is centos, and mysql was installed on it. I could access the server through ssh with cmd remotely, create database, tables and insert data. But When I tried to connect it from my WPF application, I got the error of:

```
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Error Number:87,State:0,Class:20
```

Also, the mysqld was already running on the centos because I've started it and could see its status and pid. Here is my connection string, I know something must be wrong here. I searched a lot online but none of  Can anyone help me look at it?

```
 con.ConnectionString = "Server = serverAddress:port; database = dbName; Uid = 'usernameofdatabase'; Pwd = 'password'";
```

It might be a very silly mistake but I searched a lot online couldn't get the solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, try this connection string: `"server=serverAddress;user=yourUsername;database=dbName;port=3306;password=youpPassword;"`

Comment: @Eastrall Thanks. I tried but it doesn't work. It says keyword port is not supported..